# Comment traduire « a misspent youth » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Dans les phrases anglaises suivantes :

> I had a misspent youth.
>
> He's very good at that game, I suspect a misspent youth.

C'est souvent utilisé avec une connotation sociale ou légère.

Comment peut-on exprimer « a misspent youth » en français ? Je n'ai pas pu le trouver dans un dictionnaire…

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dans l'absolu, on peut parler de *jeunesse dissolue*. Dans ce sens, [*dissolue*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dissolu)* évoque l'absence de morale, de règles. C'est moins large que l'anglais *misspent* ; *dissolu* implique qu'on a fait des choses qui étaient mal (par exemple commettre des vols, ou avoir des relations sexuelles réprouvées par la société).

S'il s'agit juste d'une jeunesse passée à faire des jeux plutôt qu'à étudier, on peut parler d'une *jeunesse gaspillée* ou *gâchée*.

Il y a aussi l'expression *folle jeunesse*, qui colle bien à *misspent youth* pour ce qui est du sens, mais ne s'utilise pas souvent en dehors de l'expression *dans ma/sa folle jeunesse*.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec toutes les propositions de Gilles. Pour traduire le second exemple (qui implique un sens non-péjoratif), je ne suis pas sûr que "gaspillée" soit idéal... Le mieux que je puisse imaginer (pour décrire ce type d'exemple où l'on imagine la personne ayant passé sa jeunesse à jouer au flipper plutôt qu'à étudier) serait un euphémistique: "peu studieuse"

Answer (score 4):

On peut le traduire par :

> Une jeunesse gaspillée

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait traduire, reprenant une expression connue, par *« jeunesse buissonière »* (qui reste aimable et n'est pas trop négatif). De même, si l'on veut insister en plus sur un côté solitaire, on pourra dire *« jeunesse sauvageonne »*.